# Python: passing arguments to __init__

Tags: python

I am new to python and have the following **init**:

```
def __init__(self, name, iMD=False, iI=False, o=0, o1=0, o2=0,
                 t=QUIC, mF=QUIC_KW, pM=0, pD=0, nF=0, pA=0, iS=0, iPA=1, h='',
                 iRC='', sC='', iM=0, iS=0, pAIR=0, 
                 pAII=0, cM='', k=0.0, t=0.0, m=0.0, mi=0.0, av=0.0, mL=0.0,
                 mD=None, iD=None, cCI=None, cCSEI=None, rfI = 0)
```

Basically when I create this object I want to pass in all the arguments except for those that have a default value of `None`.

Is there a work around in Python? I also do not want to move the order of the arguments as there is a lot of legacy code.

EDIT: Just to clarify. Yes there are default values, however, I am creating this object with non-default values that is being read in from a database. Basically I need to pass in arguments for all parameters except for mD, iD, cCI and cCSEI.

I was hoping I could construct a new object like so:
object(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, ... , arg27, , , , , arg28)

Comment: Work around for what exactly?

Comment: creating a new object without having to provide parameters for mD, iD, cCI and cCSEI

Comment: You already have that. If they have a default value you don't have to pass them at all.

Comment: basically there is only need to provide name value, you can skip all other values

Comment: the issue is I want to pass in a value to rFI that is not the default of 0

Comment: Yeah as @markcial said the only value you HAVE to pass is 'name` since it doesn't have a default value.

Comment: one of the magic things that python has is the named parameters, if you need to provide rFi value, pass the parameter like this : `callable('name',rFi=12)`

Comment: Please see edit: I need to clarify my issue further.

Comment: So you want to pass arguments without specifying keywords and have Python interpret them in the same order as in the argument spec but skipping over the ones with default of `None`?

Comment: @DSM yes that is exactly what I want

Comment: How are the values stored, then? In a list? In a dictionary? If they are in a list, are they in the order of the arguments in the`__init__()`? If they are in a dict, do the dict keys correspond to the argument names?

Comment: The values are stored in a list and they are in the order for only the first 27 arguments I then only want to pass in the 43rd arguments for rFI

Comment: So you have a list with 28 values; the first 27 ones corresponds to the parameters, but the 28th should be the 43th parameter. Is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only required argument for your method is `name`, and it must be the first argument. After that, all your arguments have default values, making them optional.  Should you want to overwrite a default, only pass that value in:

```
foo = SomeClass('hello', rfI=10)
```

Also, may I suggest using meaningful names or at least adding a [docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your method. You might also want to read the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe dictionary unpacking is what you're looking for:

```
class MyObj(object):
  def __init__(self, name, iMD=False, iI=False, o=0, o1=0, o2=0,
             t=QUIC, mF=QUIC_KW, pM=0, pD=0, nF=0, pA=0, iS=0, iPA=1, h='',
             iRC='', sC='', iM=0, iS=0, pAIR=0, 
             pAII=0, cM='', k=0.0, t=0.0, m=0.0, mi=0.0, av=0.0, mL=0.0,
             mD=None, iD=None, cCI=None, cCSEI=None, rfI = 0)

myArgs = {'rfI': 11}
m = MyObj('myname', **myArgs)
// m now has 'myname' as a name, rfI=11 and everything else as default
```

Note that this is exactly the same as saying:

```
m = MyObj('myname', rfI=11)
```

Answer (score 0):

First Your Code has an Syntax Error: `Duplicate Argument iS in function defination`. I replaced one `iS` with `iS2`. So now constructor is expecting maximum of 33 Arguments to initialize the class.

As you say you don't want to pass value to all except whose default value is `None`. Just simple pass 27 values to constructor

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, name, iMD=False, iI=False, o=0, o1=0, o2=0,
                 t=QUIC, mF=QUIC_KW, pM=0, pD=0, nF=0, pA=0, iS=0, iPA=1, h='',
                 iRC='', sC='', iM=0, iS2=0, pAIR=0, 
                 pAII=0, cM='', k=0.0, t2=0.0, m=0.0, mi=0.0, av=0.0, mL=0.0,
                 mD=None, iD=None, cCI=None, cCSEI=None, rfI = 0):
        print name, iMD


myObj = foo(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10,
    val11, val12, val13, val14, val15, val16, val17, val18, val19, val20,
    val21, val22, val23, val24, val25, val26, val27, val28)
```

Values of first 27 arguments will be overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the function below as an example because your code does not run as posted here:

```
def func(name, arg1=0, arg2=0, arg3=0, arg4=0, argSkip=None, arg6=0):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, argSkip, arg6
```

The values of the parameters should be passed from this list:

```
argument_values = [
    "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value... SURPRISE! VALUE6"
]
```

You can get the same list, without the last parameter, by using [slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
>>> argument_values[:-1]
['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']
```

You can get this sliced list and [unpack it as the arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) with the `*`:

```
func('some name here', *argument_values[:-1])
```

Of course, you need to pas the last paramenter, that is `argument_values[-1]`. In this case, just use [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
func('some name here', *argument_values[:-1], arg6=argument_values[-1])
```

Here is the complete script:

```
def func(name, arg1=0, arg2=0, arg3=0, arg4=0, argSkip=None, arg6=0):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, argSkip, arg6

argument_values = [
    "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value... SURPRISE! VALUE6"
]

func('some name here', *argument_values[:-1], arg6=argument_values[-1])
```